# Como remover 20 pixels de um elemento com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso re-calcular o tamanho de um elemento INPUT TEXT pois será dinamicamente adicionado ao lado dele um botão de 20 pixels.

tentei isso e nao funcionou

```
 $(this).width(function () { $(this).width() - 20 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `.width()` é um getter, ele só vai buscar o valor, não escrever.
Tens de usar `.css()` para isso.

```
var tamanhoInicial =  $(this).width(); // ou $(this).css('width');
$(this).css('width', tamanhoInicial - 20);
```